# Migrating NextJS static site to squarespace/cms

Tags: reactjs, next.js, squarespace

I've just started working with NextJs and I'm currently in the process of migrating an existing static site over to squarespace for easier editing. I've managed to migrate static html/css/svg assets, but am unsure how to move js files across in the `_next/static/chunks/` folder.

I've tried manually linking these files but keep getting minified js errors with no detailed information. Just wondering if there is a better/recommended way to move things across?